# SSL WWW failing to redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, no-www

I am trying to redirect all requests to a secure non-www url. But my code is failing to redirect when I vist https://www. This is the only url that is not working, can anybody help me figure out why https://www does not redirect as planned? Here is my code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  Options +FollowSymlinks

  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
  RewriteRule ^ - [env=proto:https]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^ - [env=proto:http]

  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:PROTO}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I am using Flight php for my routing.

Answer (score 0):

You added a contition to make sure your rewrites for www. are only valid for non-SSL requests.

Remove RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

Comment: I am still getting: "This site can’t provide a secure connection". I assume I am to remove it from this string: `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:PROTO}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: "I'm still getting..."? You didn't say anything about what you were getting. You said your `https://www` was not being redirected, and I told you that rewritecond was the cause. Remove it! What you say now sounds like a browser complaining about a CA, which has nothing to with a redirection which will happen "after" the SSL has already been negotiated.

If you want to avoid to present an invalid certificate for www. you can't. But this is a different issue than a redirect.

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding, but the certificate is valid for www aswell. I am trying to achieve a redirect for https www to non-www on https. As this is the only protocol not working with my current .htaccess setup.

Comment: As @ezra-s said, if you get "This site can’t provide a secure connection", it's not an redirect problem, and the problem is not in your .htaccess , it's in your SSL/TLS certificate setup .

Answer (score 0):

There might be SSL misconfiguration issue, because you are not getting redirection error. The error "This site can’t provide a secure connection" can blow due to certain reasons. Let me explain one-by-one below:

- SSL certificate is not from Trusted CA (Self Signed).
- SSL certificate has been expired.
- SSL misconfiguration can also prompt such error message.
- Time and date of your computer is not proper.
- You might be using old/insecure version of SSL certificate (SHA1).
- Using old web browser.

I suggest you check for above mentioned points.

**Suggestions:**

- Get valid certificate from trusted certificate authority, whose root chain is already in leading web browsers (i.e. [Comodo](https://www.cheapsslshop.com/blog/comodo-number-1-certificate-authority-worldwide) or Symantec).
- Renew your SSL certificate.
- Check your website in [SSL checker tool](https://sslanalyzer.comodoca.com/).
- Make time and date perfect.
- If you are using old version of SSL certificate ask your SSL provider to reissue it.
- Make your browsers up-to-date.

Hopefully this information will help you to solve your problem.